# Codeblocks inputting a text file array error

Tags: c++, c, arrays, codeblocks

i dont know where im going wrong im stuck in two problems that i have to submit for school work . its my first time ever trying to write C++ so i do apologize if this sounds stupid, but even with this i kept getting error message unknown escape sequence (i will delete this post after i get an answer out of plagiarism sake) I don't mean to offend anyone. appreciate all the help

the question that i had to solve is :
Write a C++ program that uses a two-dimensional array to store the highest and lowest temperatures for each month of the year. The program should output the average high, average low, and the highest and lowest temperatures for the year. Your program must consist of the following functions:

Function getData: This function reads and stores data in the two-dimensional array.

Function averageHigh: This function calculates and returns the average high temperature for the year.

Function averageLow: This function calculates and returns the average low temperature for the year.

Function indexHighTemp: This function returns the index of the highest high temperature in the array.

Function indexLowTemp: This function returns the index of the lowest low temperature in the array.

(These functions must all have the appropriate parameters.)

The file temperaturedata.txt is in D2L

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void getData ( ifstream& inData, double extremes [12][2] ) ;
void averageHigh ( double extremes [12][2], double& avgHigh ) ;
void averageLow ( double extremes [12][2], double& avgLow ) ;
void indexHighTemp ( double extremes [12][2], int& highMonth ) ;
void indexLowTemp ( double extremes [12][2], int& lowMonth ) ;

int main( int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[] )
{



    ifstream inData ;
    double extremes [12] [2] ;
    double avgHigh, avgLow ;
    int highMonth, lowMonth ;

  inData.open("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\C++ homework\temperature problem\temperature problem ........\temperaturedata.txt");
 if(!inData)

{
    cout << "There was an error opening the input file" << endl ;
    exit ( 1 ) ;
}
    getData ( inData, extremes ) ;


    averageHigh ( extremes, avgHigh ) ;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) ;
    cout << "The average high temperature was "  << avgHigh  << " degrees" << endl ;


    averageLow ( extremes, avgLow ) ;
    cout << "The average low temperature was "  << avgLow  << " degrees" << endl ;


    indexHighTemp ( extremes, highMonth ) ;
    cout << "The month with the highest high temperature was "  << highMonth << endl ;


    indexLowTemp ( extremes, lowMonth ) ;
    cout << "The month with the lowest low temperature was "  << lowMonth << endl ;

       return 0 ;
}

void getData ( ifstream& inData, double extremes [12][2] )

{
    int row ;

    for ( row=0; row<12; row++ )

        inData >> extremes [row][0] >> extremes [row][1] ;

        return ;
}
void averageHigh ( double extremes [12][2], double& avgHigh )

{
    double sum = 0 ;

    for ( int i=0; i<12; i++ )
        sum += extremes [i][0] ;
    avgHigh = sum/12.0 ;
    return ;
}
void averageLow ( double extremes [12][2], double& avgLow )

{
    double sum = 0 ;

    for ( int i=0; i<12; i++ )
        sum += extremes [i][1] ;
    avgLow = sum/12.0 ;
    return ;
}
void indexHighTemp ( double extremes [12][2], int& highMonth )

{
    int ind = 0 ;
    double highest = extremes [0][0] ;

    for ( int i=0; i<12; i++ )
        if ( extremes[i][0] > highest )
        {
            highest = extremes[i][0] ;
            ind = i ;
        }
        highMonth = ind ;
        return ;
}
void indexLowTemp ( double extremes [12][2], int& lowMonth )

{
    int ind = 0 ;
    double lowest = extremes [0][1] ;

    for ( int i=0; i<12; i++ )
        if ( extremes[i][1] < lowest )
        {
            lowest = extremes[i][0] ;
            ind = i ;
        }
        lowMonth = ind ;
        return ;
}
```

Comment: *I will delete this post after i get an answer out of plagiarism sake* - kind of takes the incentive out of answering, I guess the karma incentive still remains.

Comment: i mean i don't mind keeping it posted but as this website was referred by my professor im just worried that he might just take it the wrong way as we had an issue in class before with another student but i will definitly just edit it out and remove most of it and keep the solved error solution posted this way @JonnyHenly

Comment: If you want a block of code, don't use `\``.

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 im sorry i didnt quite get that

Comment: When using stack overflow, you can write a block of code by indenting the lines by 4 spaces. You can also write some code in a paragraph by wrapping it like this: `\`code\``. But when you have already indented your block of code, you don't need to add `\`` in front of it.

Comment: oh ok! Thank you for the clarification :D. @v7d8dpo4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the backslash character, you should use two backslashes. Use `'\\'` if you want the backslash character. Use `"\\"` if you want it in a string. This is because the backslash character means the beginning of an escape sequence.

Replace line 25 with

```
inData.open("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\C++ homework\\temperature problem\\temperature problem ........\\temperaturedata.txt");
```

Comment: It Worked this way, thank you so much for the help!!